# Spring Boot Config Client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

Developing microservices using Spring Boot, and are currently working on containerizing our applications. However, I can't seem to figure out best practices for Cloud Config client.

How do I best update the cloud config server for the docker container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In practice, the  your containerized config application should be pulling the config from some centralized repository where configs are checked in and from there your microservices or containerized app will pull the config for further process.